# Importing from Custom E-Commerce Platform to Magento 2 (MySQL to M2)

Tags: magento2, product, database, import

I need to import Products, Customers and Order History from a custom e-commerce platform into a new Magento 2 implementation. Ideally the extension or cloud service would allow us to connect directly to MySQL (source) on the custom platform and sync all products, customers and order history with Magento v2.3 (destination).

I've looked into Skyvia and FireBearStudio Improved Import which appear to offer the features closest to what I need. FireBearStudio hasn't officially released their direct MySQL support yet, so right now that doesn't seem to be a viable option.

If you have any personal knowledge of any other options that might fit my requirements, please let me know? Also, I would be interested in learning about your personal experience with Skyvia and FireBearStudio.